# How to convert the following dictionary format column into different format in Hive or Presto?

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I have a Hive table as below:

| event_name | attendees_per_countries |
| --- | --- |
| a | {'US':5} |
| b | {'US':4, 'UK': 3, 'CA': 2} |
| c | {'UK':2, 'CA': 1} |

And I want to get a new table like below:

| country | number_of_people |
| --- | --- |
| US | 9 |
| UK | 5 |
| CA | 4 |

How to write a query in Hive or Presto?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following:

If the column type for `attendees_per_countries` is a string, you may use the following:

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
    select 
        event_name, 
        str_to_map(
            regexp_replace(attendees_per_countries,'[{|}]',''),
            ',',
            ':'
        ) as attendees_per_countries 
    FROM
        raw_data
        
)
select 
    regexp_replace(cm.key,"[' ]","") as country,
    SUM(cm.value) as no_of_people
from sample_data
lateral view explode(attendees_per_countries) cm
GROUP BY regexp_replace(cm.key,"[' ]","")
ORDER BY no_of_people DESC
```

However, if the column type for `attendees_per_countries` is already a `map` then you may use the following

```sql
select 
    regexp_replace(cm.key,"[' ]","") as country,
    SUM(cm.value) as no_of_people
from sample_data
lateral view explode(attendees_per_countries) cm
GROUP BY regexp_replace(cm.key,"[' ]","")
ORDER BY no_of_people DESC
```

Full reproducible example below

```sql
with raw_data AS (
    select 'a' as event_name, "{'US':5}" as attendees_per_countries
    UNION ALL 
    select 'b', "{'US':4, 'UK': 3, 'CA': 2}"
    UNION ALL 
    select 'c', "{'UK':2, 'CA': 1}"
),
sample_data AS (
    select 
        event_name, 
        str_to_map(
            regexp_replace(attendees_per_countries,'[{}]',''),
            ',',
            ':'
        ) as attendees_per_countries 
    FROM
        raw_data
        
)
select 
    regexp_replace(cm.key,"[' ]","") as country,
    SUM(cm.value) as no_of_people
from sample_data
lateral view explode(attendees_per_countries) cm
GROUP BY regexp_replace(cm.key,"[' ]","")
ORDER BY no_of_people DESC
```

Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

In presto if you have `attendees_per_countries` as map you can use `map_values` and then sum them with `array_sum`/`reduce` (I need to use later because Athena does not support former one). If not - you can treat your data as JSON and cast it to `MAP(VARCHAR, INTEGER)` and then use the mentioned functions:

```sql
WITH dataset(event_name, attendees_per_countries) AS (
   VALUES 
('a',   JSON '{"US":5}'),
('b',   JSON '{"US":4, "UK": 3, "CA": 2}'),
('c',   JSON '{"UK":2, "CA": 1}')
 ) 
 
SELECT event_name as country,
       reduce(
               map_values(cast(attendees_per_countries as MAP(VARCHAR, INTEGER))),
               0,
               (agg, curr) -> agg + curr,
               s -> s
           )      as number_of_people
FROM dataset
order by 2 desc
```

Output:

| country | number_of_people |
| --- | --- |
| b | 9 |
| a | 5 |
| c | 3 |